# Using AWK to substitute

Tags: linux, bash, loops, awk, latex

First time attempting to tinker with AWK and use it to take input from a file like the following:

*data.csv*

> James,Jones,30,Mr,Main St
> Melissa,Greene,200,Mrs,Wall St 
> Robert,Krupp,410,Mr,Random St

and process it into a LaTeX Template

*data.tex*

```
\newcommand{\customertitle}{XYZ} %ggf. \
\newcommand{\customerName}{Max Sample} % Name \
\newcommand{\customerStreet}{Str} % Street \
\newcommand{\customerZIP}{12345} % ZIP
```

First I tried to replace the customer name this way

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}{print $1 " " $2 }' data.csv | xargs -I{} sed "s/Max Sample/{}/" data.tex > names
```

which gave me a merged file.. and therefore I subsequently attempted to render the file as single .tex files by inserting a keyword "#TEST" at the end of the original file, so I could use it as a Record Separator to get me back to single files with the following command:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=RS="#TEST"} {i=1}{ while (i <= NF) {print $i >>"final"NR".tex"; i++}}' names
```

Even though that worked for this one field, for multiple fields it doesn't seem to be a proper solution as is though. (title, street, zip code)

That's why I'm now attempting to get it working with the `gsub` action in AWK. 
Tried those different approaches. Based on what I could find regarding it thus far, that's what I came up with:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=","}NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$4;next}{gsub ("XYZ",a[FNR]);print}' data.csv data.tex
```

which replaces XYZ with  nothing

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=","}NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$4;next}RS="#TEST"{for (i in a) {gsub("XYZ",i);print}}' data.csv data.tex \
```

which counts four times to 7

Tried those also with the merged file, ie. the "names" output from the first command and didn't get it to work.
What am I missing? Can the `gsub` command not replace a string with an array? Is a loop required?

I'm stuck, hope someone can help out here

Comment: you know there are latex package to input csv files?

Comment: see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/216127/36296 for a simple serial letter from a csv file

Comment: I did it out of interest and studies for awk, so I would love to get it to work this way, but appreciate you sharing it , thank you!

Comment: Ah, in this case have fun playing with awk :)

Comment: Can you make an output example from input data?

Answer (score 1):

I hope it is your case.
Create a file csv_to_latex.awk and put this code:

```
BEGIN{
    FS=","
    while(getline < latex > 0) {
    
        lax_array[$0]
    }
}
    
{
    name = $1" "$2
    zip = $3
    status = $4
    street = $5

    for (lax_key in lax_array)
    {    
        if (lax_key ~ /XYZ/)
        {
            gsub("{XYZ}", "{"status"}", lax_key)
            print lax_key
        }
        else if (lax_key ~ /Max Sample/)
        {
            gsub("{Max Sample}", "{"name"}", lax_key)
            print lax_key
        }
        else if (lax_key ~ /Str/)
        {
            gsub("{Str}", "{"street"}", lax_key)
            print lax_key
        }
        else if (lax_key ~ /12345/)
        {
            gsub("{12345}", "{"zip"}", lax_key)
            print lax_key
        }
    }
}
```

To execute this code, use in terminal:

```
awk -v latex="data.tex" -f csv_to_latex.awk data.csv
```

The output:

```
\newcommand{\customertitle}{Mr} %ggf. \
\newcommand{\customerName}{James Jones} % Name \
\newcommand{\customerStreet}{Main St} % Street \
\newcommand{\customerZIP}{30} % ZIP
\newcommand{\customertitle}{Mrs} %ggf. \
\newcommand{\customerName}{Melissa Greene} % Name \
\newcommand{\customerStreet}{Wall St} % Street \
\newcommand{\customerZIP}{200} % ZIP
\newcommand{\customertitle}{Mr} %ggf. \
\newcommand{\customerName}{Robert Krupp} % Name \
\newcommand{\customerStreet}{Random St} % Street \
\newcommand{\customerZIP}{410} % ZIP
```

Comment: That works beautifully, thank you!

The TeX file has actually more records, which I omitted for readability reasons, but I might get it to work

Comment: `while(getline < latex > 0)` is undefined behavior, it should be `while((getline < latex) > 0)` to be safe and portable across all awks. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline if you're ever considering using getline (which you don't actually need in this case).

Answer (score 1):

I feel like doing replaces is unnecessary and would probably approach it like this:

```sh
awk -F, -v po='\\newcommand{\\%s}{%s} %s \n' '{
    printf po, "customertitle", $4, "%ggf. \\"
    printf po, "customerName", $1" "$2, "% Name \\"
    printf po, "customerStreet", $NF, "% Street \\"
    printf po, "customerZip", $3, "% Zip"
}' data.csv
```

output:

```
\newcommand{\customertitle}{Mr} %ggf. \
\newcommand{\customerName}{James Jones} % Name \
\newcommand{\customerStreet}{Main St} % Street \
\newcommand{\customerZip}{30} % Zip
\newcommand{\customertitle}{Mrs} %ggf. \
\newcommand{\customerName}{Melissa Greene} % Name \
\newcommand{\customerStreet}{Wall St} % Street \
\newcommand{\customerZip}{200} % Zip
\newcommand{\customertitle}{Mr} %ggf. \
\newcommand{\customerName}{Robert Krupp} % Name \
\newcommand{\customerStreet}{Random St} % Street \
\newcommand{\customerZip}{410} % Zip
```